# How do I configure Kickstart network settings with Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: server, netplan, kickstart

I saw that in Ubuntu Server versions 16.04 and prior, there used to be a way to auto-configure the SystemV networking part of the Ubuntu OS in unattended installs via Kickstart files. However it seems that the Kickstart project or "Ubuntu Kickstart project" has failed to incorporate Netplan (probably because the original project is Fedora-based) into Kickstart, thus breaking the networking configuration because Kickstart itself hasn't fully migrated from SystemV to Netplan. This issue is further excacerbated in documentation that Ubuntu continues to host on its own site (see link below) and I'm trying to figure out how to get this resolved. Ideas?

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/ch04s06.html

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/system-config-kickstart/+bug/1801781